# Differential equation undamped system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

[Question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLWy8.png)

How can I solve this question?

An object weighting 8 pounds is suspended from a spring stretching it 0.5 feet. The weight, which
is at rest in the equilibrium position, is struck an upward blow of magnitude 1 pound. Assuming
no damping, determine the velocity with which the weight leaves the equilibrium position (g = 32
ft/s2).

Comment: I think the spring is irrelevant here, relevant is "at rest" and "a blow of 1 pound", as the question is only for the velocity in the at-rest position, that is, the velocity change directly after the blow. So should it be $\frac12m_{weight}v^2=m_{blow}g$?